# Android Studio 3.6.3 Error: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3 available for offline mode. Gradle Version: 5.6.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How are you doing?
I am trying to built one basic android application using the latest Android Studio 3.6.3 which was built on 14th April 2020. Below is my issue:

I clicked on Start New Project Option from AS 3.6.3
Gave its name as MyFirstAndroidApp
Then as usual Gradle Sync started automatically. I am getting the below 3 errors and its already my 3rd day.

1. Caused by:
   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
2. Caused by:
       org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not
       resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
3. Caused by:
       org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached
       version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3 available for
       offline mode.

[image: Error Box]

Please help me, I need the answer for Android Studio Version 3.6.3 and for Gradle 5.6.4
Early help is appreciated. Thank You!

Below are the errors which i get after toggling the Online mode:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 4):

You can toggle the offline mode via the gradle menu bar.

[image: Gradle Offline mode]

Comment: Thank you so much @Monster Brain. Below is the screen shot for more errors now.

Comment: After doing the above setting my issue did not get resolved. It says connection timeout and also Could not get resource gradle 3.6.3 pom. I have added the screen shot in the above question

Comment: In the build.gradle file in the project path (not app folder), what is inside 
.. maybe the repository is missing ..
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

Comment: buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Comment: The above is what the build.gradle looks like. I added maven as it was not there in the repositories but still getting the same issue as per the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have Android Studio setup in Offline mode and Gradle needs internet access to update some things.

Go to Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and uncheck Offline-work.
On Windows it might be Settings instead of Preferences, I'm not sure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You Razvan for Your reply. Can you please let me know where is this setting? I tried in File>> Settings>> Build,Execution,Deployment>> Gradle but there was no option to uncheck the Offline-work

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I don't know the exact windows path, but I see that Monster Brain provided a faster solution.